# Fresh TexLive 2022 install: biblatex "Patching \MakeUppercase failed" error

Tags: biblatex, errors, texlive, installing, tlmgr

I have just made a fresh install of TexLive 2022 following the quickinstall guide (https://tug.org/texlive/quickinstall.html) including adding the paths to their corresponding variables. I am not using the version that can be installed in Ubuntu using apt-get because that gives me problems of compatibility between the biber and biblatex versions.

The problem I'm having now is that when I run pdflatex it produces the following error

```
error: [biblatex] Patching \MakeUppercase failed at \begin{document}
error: [biblatex] Patching \MakeLowercase failed at \begin{document}
```

Digging around I have seen that this is supposed to be fixed in a patch of biblatex that is available in CTAN but tlmgr says that biblatex is already updated and so either tlmgr doesn't know of that version or I'm not sure what can be going on. Any help is appreciated!

This is a minimal example that reproduces the error

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[backend=biber]{biblatex}

\begin{document}

Some text

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

The full log is

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.141592653-2.6-1.40.24 (TeX Live 2022) (preloaded format=pdflatex 2022.8.18)  18 AUG 2022 18:34
entering extended mode
 restricted \write18 enabled.
 %&-line parsing enabled.
**test.tex
(./test.tex
LaTeX2e <2022-06-01> patch level 5
L3 programming layer <2022-08-05>
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls
Document Class: article 2021/10/04 v1.4n Standard LaTeX document class
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size10.clo
File: size10.clo 2021/10/04 v1.4n Standard LaTeX file (size option)
)
\c@part=\count185
\c@section=\count186
\c@subsection=\count187
\c@subsubsection=\count188
\c@paragraph=\count189
\c@subparagraph=\count190
\c@figure=\count191
\c@table=\count192
\abovecaptionskip=\skip47
\belowcaptionskip=\skip48
\bibindent=\dimen138
)
(/home/julio/texmf/tex/latex/biblatex/biblatex.sty
Package: biblatex 2019/12/01 v3.14 programmable bibliographies (PK/MW)

(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pdftexcmds/pdftexcmds.sty
Package: pdftexcmds 2020-06-27 v0.33 Utility functions of pdfTeX for LuaTeX (HO
)

(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/infwarerr/infwarerr.sty
Package: infwarerr 2019/12/03 v1.5 Providing info/warning/error messages (HO)
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/iftex/iftex.sty
Package: iftex 2022/02/03 v1.0f TeX engine tests
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/ltxcmds/ltxcmds.sty
Package: ltxcmds 2020-05-10 v1.25 LaTeX kernel commands for general use (HO)
)
Package pdftexcmds Info: \pdf@primitive is available.
Package pdftexcmds Info: \pdf@ifprimitive is available.
Package pdftexcmds Info: \pdfdraftmode found.
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/etoolbox/etoolbox.sty
Package: etoolbox 2020/10/05 v2.5k e-TeX tools for LaTeX (JAW)
\etb@tempcnta=\count193
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/keyval.sty
Package: keyval 2022/05/29 v1.15 key=value parser (DPC)
\KV@toks@=\toks16
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/kvoptions/kvoptions.sty
Package: kvoptions 2022-06-15 v3.15 Key value format for package options (HO)

(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/kvsetkeys/kvsetkeys.sty
Package: kvsetkeys 2019/12/15 v1.18 Key value parser (HO)
))
(/home/julio/texmf/tex/latex/logreq/logreq.sty
Package: logreq 2010/08/04 v1.0 xml request logger
\lrq@indent=\count194

(/home/julio/texmf/tex/latex/logreq/logreq.def
File: logreq.def 2010/08/04 v1.0 logreq spec v1.0
))
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/ifthen.sty
Package: ifthen 2022/04/13 v1.1d Standard LaTeX ifthen package (DPC)
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/url/url.sty
\Urlmuskip=\muskip16
Package: url 2013/09/16  ver 3.4  Verb mode for urls, etc.
)
\c@tabx@nest=\count195
\c@listtotal=\count196
\c@listcount=\count197
\c@liststart=\count198
\c@liststop=\count199
\c@citecount=\count266
\c@citetotal=\count267
\c@multicitecount=\count268
\c@multicitetotal=\count269
\c@instcount=\count270
\c@maxnames=\count271
\c@minnames=\count272
\c@maxitems=\count273
\c@minitems=\count274
\c@citecounter=\count275
\c@maxcitecounter=\count276
\c@savedcitecounter=\count277
\c@uniquelist=\count278
\c@uniquename=\count279
\c@refsection=\count280
\c@refsegment=\count281
\c@maxextratitle=\count282
\c@maxextratitleyear=\count283
\c@maxextraname=\count284
\c@maxextradate=\count285
\c@maxextraalpha=\count286
\c@abbrvpenalty=\count287
\c@highnamepenalty=\count288
\c@lownamepenalty=\count289
\c@maxparens=\count290
\c@parenlevel=\count291
\blx@tempcnta=\count292
\blx@tempcntb=\count293
\blx@tempcntc=\count294
\blx@maxsection=\count295
\blx@maxsegment@0=\count296
\blx@notetype=\count297
\blx@parenlevel@text=\count298
\blx@parenlevel@foot=\count299
\blx@sectionciteorder@0=\count300
\blx@entrysetcounter=\count301
\labelnumberwidth=\skip49
\labelalphawidth=\skip50
\biblabelsep=\skip51
\bibitemsep=\skip52
\bibnamesep=\skip53
\bibinitsep=\skip54
\bibparsep=\skip55
\bibhang=\skip56
\blx@bcfin=\read2
\blx@bcfout=\write3
\blx@langwohyphens=\language87
\c@mincomprange=\count302
\c@maxcomprange=\count303
\c@mincompwidth=\count304
Package biblatex Info: Trying to load biblatex default data model...
Package biblatex Info: ... file 'blx-dm.def' found.

(/home/julio/texmf/tex/latex/biblatex/blx-dm.def
File: blx-dm.def 2019/12/01 v3.14 biblatex localization (PK/MW)
)
Package biblatex Info: Trying to load biblatex custom data model...
Package biblatex Info: ... file 'biblatex-dm.cfg' not found.
\c@afterword=\count305
\c@savedafterword=\count306
\c@annotator=\count307
\c@savedannotator=\count308
\c@author=\count309
\c@savedauthor=\count310
\c@bookauthor=\count311
\c@savedbookauthor=\count312
\c@commentator=\count313
\c@savedcommentator=\count314
\c@editor=\count315
\c@savededitor=\count316
\c@editora=\count317
\c@savededitora=\count318
\c@editorb=\count319
\c@savededitorb=\count320
\c@editorc=\count321
\c@savededitorc=\count322
\c@foreword=\count323
\c@savedforeword=\count324
\c@holder=\count325
\c@savedholder=\count326
\c@introduction=\count327
\c@savedintroduction=\count328
\c@namea=\count329
\c@savednamea=\count330
\c@nameb=\count331
\c@savednameb=\count332
\c@namec=\count333
\c@savednamec=\count334
\c@translator=\count335
\c@savedtranslator=\count336
\c@shortauthor=\count337
\c@savedshortauthor=\count338
\c@shorteditor=\count339
\c@savedshorteditor=\count340
\c@labelname=\count341
\c@savedlabelname=\count342
\c@institution=\count343
\c@savedinstitution=\count344
\c@lista=\count345
\c@savedlista=\count346
\c@listb=\count347
\c@savedlistb=\count348
\c@listc=\count349
\c@savedlistc=\count350
\c@listd=\count351
\c@savedlistd=\count352
\c@liste=\count353
\c@savedliste=\count354
\c@listf=\count355
\c@savedlistf=\count356
\c@location=\count357
\c@savedlocation=\count358
\c@organization=\count359
\c@savedorganization=\count360
\c@origlocation=\count361
\c@savedoriglocation=\count362
\c@origpublisher=\count363
\c@savedorigpublisher=\count364
\c@publisher=\count365
\c@savedpublisher=\count366
\c@language=\count367
\c@savedlanguage=\count368
\c@origlanguage=\count369
\c@savedoriglanguage=\count370
\c@pageref=\count371
\c@savedpageref=\count372
\shorthandwidth=\skip57
\shortjournalwidth=\skip58
\shortserieswidth=\skip59
\shorttitlewidth=\skip60
\shortauthorwidth=\skip61
\shorteditorwidth=\skip62
\locallabelnumberwidth=\skip63
\locallabelalphawidth=\skip64
\localshorthandwidth=\skip65
\localshortjournalwidth=\skip66
\localshortserieswidth=\skip67
\localshorttitlewidth=\skip68
\localshortauthorwidth=\skip69
\localshorteditorwidth=\skip70
Package biblatex Info: Trying to load compatibility code...
Package biblatex Info: ... file 'blx-compat.def' found.

(/home/julio/texmf/tex/latex/biblatex/blx-compat.def
File: blx-compat.def 2019/12/01 v3.14 biblatex compatibility (PK/MW)
)
Package biblatex Info: Trying to load generic definitions...
Package biblatex Info: ... file 'biblatex.def' found.

(/home/julio/texmf/tex/latex/biblatex/biblatex.def
File: biblatex.def 2019/12/01 v3.14 biblatex compatibility (PK/MW)
\c@textcitecount=\count373
\c@textcitetotal=\count374
\c@textcitemaxnames=\count375
\c@biburlbigbreakpenalty=\count376
\c@biburlbreakpenalty=\count377
\c@biburlnumpenalty=\count378
\c@biburlucpenalty=\count379
\c@biburllcpenalty=\count380
\biburlbigskip=\muskip17
\biburlnumskip=\muskip18
\biburlucskip=\muskip19
\biburllcskip=\muskip20
\c@smartand=\count381
)
Package biblatex Info: Trying to load bibliography style 'numeric'...
Package biblatex Info: ... file 'numeric.bbx' found.

(/home/julio/texmf/tex/latex/biblatex/bbx/numeric.bbx
File: numeric.bbx 2019/12/01 v3.14 biblatex bibliography style (PK/MW)
Package biblatex Info: Trying to load bibliography style 'standard'...
Package biblatex Info: ... file 'standard.bbx' found.

(/home/julio/texmf/tex/latex/biblatex/bbx/standard.bbx
File: standard.bbx 2019/12/01 v3.14 biblatex bibliography style (PK/MW)
\c@bbx:relatedcount=\count382
\c@bbx:relatedtotal=\count383
))
Package biblatex Info: Trying to load citation style 'numeric'...
Package biblatex Info: ... file 'numeric.cbx' found.

(/home/julio/texmf/tex/latex/biblatex/cbx/numeric.cbx
File: numeric.cbx 2019/12/01 v3.14 biblatex citation style (PK/MW)
Package biblatex Info: Redefining '\cite'.
Package biblatex Info: Redefining '\parencite'.
Package biblatex Info: Redefining '\footcite'.
Package biblatex Info: Redefining '\footcitetext'.
Package biblatex Info: Redefining '\smartcite'.
Package biblatex Info: Redefining '\supercite'.
Package biblatex Info: Redefining '\textcite'.
Package biblatex Info: Redefining '\textcites'.
Package biblatex Info: Redefining '\cites'.
Package biblatex Info: Redefining '\parencites'.
Package biblatex Info: Redefining '\smartcites'.
)
Package biblatex Info: Trying to load configuration file...
Package biblatex Info: ... file 'biblatex.cfg' found.

(/home/julio/texmf/tex/latex/biblatex/biblatex.cfg
File: biblatex.cfg 
))
\@quotelevel=\count384
\@quotereset=\count385


! Package biblatex Error: Patching \MakeUppercase failed.

See the biblatex package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              
                                                  
l.6 \begin{document}
                    
? q
OK, entering \batchmode...

! Package biblatex Error: Patching \MakeLowercase failed.

See the biblatex package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              
                                                  
l.6 \begin{document}
                    
This is an internal issue typically caused by a conflict
between biblatex and some other package. Modifying
the package loading order may fix the problem.


(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3backend/l3backend-pdftex.def
File: l3backend-pdftex.def 2022-08-05 L3 backend support: PDF output (pdfTeX)
\l__color_backend_stack_int=\count386
\l__pdf_internal_box=\box51
) (./test.aux)
\openout1 = `test.aux'.

LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OML/cmm/m/it on input line 6.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 6.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMS/cmsy/m/n on input line 6.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 6.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OT1/cmr/m/n on input line 6.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 6.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for T1/cmr/m/n on input line 6.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 6.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for TS1/cmr/m/n on input line 6.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 6.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMX/cmex/m/n on input line 6.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 6.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for U/cmr/m/n on input line 6.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 6.
Package biblatex Info: Trying to load language 'english'...
Package biblatex Info: ... file 'english.lbx' found.
 (/home/julio/texmf/tex/latex/biblatex/lbx/english.lbx
File: english.lbx 2019/12/01 v3.14 biblatex localization (PK/MW)
)
Package biblatex Info: Input encoding 'utf8' detected.
Package biblatex Info: Automatic encoding selection.
(biblatex)             Assuming data encoding 'utf8'.
\openout3 = `test.bcf'.

Package biblatex Info: Trying to load bibliographic data...
Package biblatex Info: ... file 'test.bbl' not found.
No file test.bbl.
Package biblatex Info: Reference section=0 on input line 6.
Package biblatex Info: Reference segment=0 on input line 6.

LaTeX Warning: Empty bibliography on input line 10.

 [1

{/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-var/fonts/map/pdftex/updmap/pdftex.map}] (./test
.aux)
Package logreq Info: Writing requests to 'test.run.xml'.
\openout1 = `test.run.xml'.

 ) 
Here is how much of TeX's memory you used:
 7825 strings out of 477678
 150988 string characters out of 5829475
 836102 words of memory out of 5000000
 26624 multiletter control sequences out of 15000+600000
 469259 words of font info for 28 fonts, out of 8000000 for 9000
 1141 hyphenation exceptions out of 8191
 54i,5n,62p,677b,743s stack positions out of 10000i,1000n,20000p,200000b,200000s
</usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmr10.pfb>
Output written on test.pdf (1 page, 12600 bytes).
PDF statistics:
 13 PDF objects out of 1000 (max. 8388607)
 7 compressed objects within 1 object stream
 0 named destinations out of 1000 (max. 500000)
 1 words of extra memory for PDF output out of 10000 (max. 10000000)
```

Comment: make a small example and show the complete log-file.

Comment: you have a local, old biblatex file in /home/julio/texmf/tex/latex/biblatex/biblatex.sty. Delete it.

Comment: That solved it! Thank you!

Comment: I naturally meant, delete everything in the folder.

Comment: check you have no other files in `/home/julio/texmf/tex/latex` that mask standard files, basically remove anything under there that you did not write.